# Solving Xamarin iOS Emit PlatformNotSupportedException with intepreter

Tags: ios, xamarin, interpreter, emit

we're using https://github.com/firelyteam FHIR library in a Xamaring application.
When testing in iOS we discovered the PlatformNotSupportedException because of the use of Emit.
We then discovered we could use the Xamarin interpreter: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/introducing-xamarin-ios-interpreter/
and it just works!

I have some questions/doubts:

1. is there any difference between the "Enable the mono interpreter" option or adding "--interpreter" to "Additional mtouch arguments"
2. is it possible to limit the interpreter to specific libraries? I'm under the impression is now globally enabled. I tried with "--interpreter=FHIR.HL7.Support" but I'm not sure it's working: inspecting the .ipa seems to containe .aotdata for everything. I was under the impression that aotdata was not produced when interpreted
3. can you suggest better solutions?

Thanks a lot

Comment: To your first question, I think there is no difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use --interpreter=assemblyname,.... to only allow the interpreter to work on just those assemblies, i.e. include the IL in only those assemblies.